# Qual a origem da expressão "o fim da picada"?

Tags: expressões

Se, em geral, "picada" é uma coisa negativa, pois remete a dor e coceira, como pode ser que "o fim da picada" seja uma expressão também negativa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Picada* (Aulete, 3)](https://www.aulete.com.br/picada) é também “caminho aberto em mata fechada a golpes de facão ou foice”. E a minha interpretação foi sempre que *o fim da picada* é ’o fim do caminho’, e quando chegamos ao fim do caminho, não podemos avançar mais, e ficamos numa situação complicada. Esta é também a intertretação no [Wikicionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9_o_fim_da_picada) e na [revista *Veja* (2013)](https://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/de-onde-vem-a-expressao-fim-da-picada/):

> Pois. O fim da picada nada mais é que o fim do caminho, o ponto além do qual já não se pode ou não se quer avançar.

Agora, o que eu não sabia era que ***o fim da picada* já significou também ’muito bom’**. Só depois é que passou a significar apenas, nas palavras do [Aulete (verbete *fim*, lá mesmo em baixo)](https://www.aulete.com.br/fim), “desagradável, penoso, inconveniente”.

### Evolução do uso

Até princípios do século XX, só encontrei mesmo no sentido literal, tipo: “Precisa-se saber quem é o proprietario de um terreno sito no **fim da picada** em seguimento á rua de Leopoldo” ([*Jornal do Commercio*, Rio de Janeiro,1900](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=364568_09&pesq=%22fim%20da%20picada%22&pasta=ano%20190&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=255)). Depois também encontrei no sentido figurado de ir até ao fim, à conclusão, às últimas consequências. N’[*A Verdade* (Cidade de Cabo Verde, MG, 1919)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=847810&pesq=%22fim%20da%20picada%22&pasta=ano%20191&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=3), diz-se que o Delegado “chegará ao fim da picada”, querendo dizer que ele irá concluir a investigação e capturar o criminoso. Ou n’[(*O Jornal* (Rio de Janeiro, 1962)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=110523_06&pesq=%22fim%20da%20picada%22&pasta=ano%20196&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=23802): “Mulher é assim. Quando toma partido político se apaixona. Vai ao fim da picada”. Mais um [exemplo de 1965](https://books.google.pt/books?id=RsgrAAAAYAAJ&q=%22o%20fim%20da%20picada%22&dq=%22o%20fim%20da%20picada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC7ZCX-7fzAhULRvEDHQ9qDPA4FBDoAXoECAIQAg).

A minha surpresa foi quando vi na [Grande Enciclopédia Portuguesa e Brasileira de 1936](https://books.google.pt/books?id=j8AqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22fim%20da%20picada%22&dq=%22fim%20da%20picada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU4uL_9bfzAhVrRPEDHZDoDtQQ6AF6BAgSEAI) que *fim da picada* é “superlativo de bom”! E encontrei alguns exemplos desse uso. [*O Paiz* (Rio de Janeiro, 1920)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=178691_05&pesq=%22fim%20da%20picada%22&pasta=ano%20192&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=356) noticia uma festa de Carnaval que ia “ser uma coisa estupenda, que nunca se viu em logar nenhum”, e que ia ser, “**incontestavelmente, o fim da picada!!!**” Em anúncios no [*Lavoura e Commercio* de Uberaba (1936)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=830461&pesq=%22fim%20da%20picada%22&pasta=ano%20193&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=17936), a “Loja Benção”, grande “emporio de tecidos” sem “concorrencia em seus preços”, gaba-se de ser “**o fim da picada**”. Ainda se encontram exemplos deste uso nos anos 50 e 60. Este [*Boletim*… (São Paulo, 1954)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gFUhAQAAIAAJ&q=%22o%20fim%20da%20picada%22&dq=%22o%20fim%20da%20picada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjiv43U97fzAhXgSfEDHSQhAN4Q6AF6BAgPEAI), depois de explicar que os sul-africanos tinham desenvolvido um boi muito bem adaptado aos trópicos, mas que o brasileiro não era pior, continua:

> […] os moçambicanos não deverão ficar na suposição de que, em matéria de gado de talho no trópico, o Africander é a **quintessência ou o “fim da picada”**, conforme se diz ente nós.

E [Mariazinha Congíli (*Môco de recados*, 1966)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ZvAQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22o%20fim%20da%20picada%22&dq=%22o%20fim%20da%20picada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHnbG8gLjzAhUgS_EDHSAUAcE4KBDoAXoECBIQAg) tem:

> — Qual é a profissão dêle?
> — Ah! Isso não sei. Mas tem um carro que é o máximo! Vou lhe dizer: perto dêle, até o Tony Curtis fica sem graça! E o charme? Poderia dar lições ao Laurence Olivier. Tem uma personalidade mais marcante que o príncipe Philip de Inglaterra. Minha filha, **êle é o fim da picada**…

Mas por esta altura também já se encontram exemplos em que *o fim da picada* é uma coisa má, como em [João Bettencourt (1965)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=i7pTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22o%20fim%20da%20picada%22&dq=%22o%20fim%20da%20picada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC7ZCX-7fzAhULRvEDHQ9qDPA4FBDoAXoECBQQAg):

> […] nunca vi nada pagar tão mal no Brasil quanto jornal. Pior que jornal só mesmo tradução, que **é o fim da picada**. Agora, o supra-sumo é que o intelectual é tão explorado, tão explorado […]

Portanto, pelos vistos, por volta de 1950, 1960, *o fim da picada* era usado com no sentido ’o extremo, o máximo’, que poderia ser bom ou mau, e só mais tarde se passou a ser, ainda ’extremo, máximo’, mas já só no mau sentido.

Comment: Ja tentou no google

Comment: @ClMend, se eu já tentei no Google? Tentar o quê?

Comment: A expressão é de uso corrente pelas bandas de cá, mas eu desconhecia essa evolução.  +1

Comment: @Centaurus, pois, fiquei muito surpreendido quando vi aquele "superlativo de bom". Eu só conheço o *fim da picada* das bandas daí, mas só me lembro de ter ouvido com sentido negativo.